# My App on App Store updated itself without releasing an update

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, updates

yesterday i saw on my iPhone that was an update of one of my apps without nothing updated, so i checked in iTunesConnect and nothing, no updated released.

Is it possibile? Also to my friends is happened at same day.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has happened again in the past when a bug with bitcode was discovered. When you submit your app to Apple with Bitcode enabled, Apple can (and will) build and optimise your app for each processor architecture. So it is possible that for some reason Apple triggered a rebuild of your app and that is the reason that you saw an update.

Comment: Perfect! There is an official document where i can read some other details?

Comment: @EdoardoCortese https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html